# How to insert "n" rows into an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: ms-office

I simply want to insert "n" rows. None of the resources that I have found have stated how to do this. The closest I have seen is "select same number of rows". That is fraught with problems.  Any hints / VBA code or other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, even though visually it looks like it is fraught with problems.

I've been doing this for decades, literally, and I use Excel almost every day.

Ex: insert 5 empty rows between row 4 and row 5:

[image]

Click on the numeral 5 at the far left, then entire row is selected.

A small yellow box appears at the lower-left of the selected area.

[image]

Hold-drag the small yellow box down to row 10. Release the mouse button.

[image]

Right-click and choose Insert

[image]

Boom! 5 empty rows!

[image]

It can't get any simpler than that!

Comment: Thx - it's actually green in MacOs but in any case it does work. Never noticed that box before.  Any other thoughts/hints on what you've uncovered in excel?

Answer (score 1):

I just select 5 or 7 or 12 whatever rows on the lhs and then right-click and insert - job done...

Comment: i'll try that now.  Yes that works. Do you know how to do this with keyboard only (/mostly) ?